# How do I delete the rows that are duplicated in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I want to delete the rows that have the same article name (articulo) or simply that it is not added if it is already in the table

Model:

```
class MetaArt(db.Base):
    __tablename__ = 'metadata'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    fecha = Column(Date)
    articulo = Column(String(1000))
    autores = Column(String(1000))
    affili = Column(String(2000))
    categoria_articulo = Column(String(200))
    version = Column(String(500))
    version2 = Column(String(500))
```

I want to run this SQL Query:

```
WITH articulos_repetidos AS (
    SELECT MIN(id) as id, articulo FROM metadata 
            GROUP BY articulo
            HAVING COUNT(*)>1
)
DELETE FROM metadata
    WHERE id not IN (
        SELECT id FROM articulos_repetidos
    ) and articulo IN (SELECT articulo FROM articulos_repetidos);
```

My question is how to build such statement in SQLAlchemy core?

Comment: What is your question? How to run a text statement (as above)? How to construct such a statement in SQLAlchemy core? What have you tried? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: My question is how to build such statement in SQLAlchemy core? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
subq = (
    select(func.min(MetaArt.id).label("id"), MetaArt.articulo)
    .group_by(MetaArt.articulo)
    .having(func.count(literal("*")) > 1)
)
cte = subq.cte("articulos_repetidos")

stmt = (
    delete(MetaArt)
    .where(~MetaArt.id.in_(select(cte.c.id)))
    .where(MetaArt.articulo.in_(select(cte.c.articulo)))
)
```